# How can i rotate an Cube

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, glm-math

I'am new to OpenGL  and i have a Question about how can i rotate my Cube around the Y-Axis.

I have an Model,Projection and View Matrix,with which i display my Cube.But i dont understand how i can animate my Cube.What i thought of was, that i use the Model-Matrix for that.

For Example :`mat4 model = rotate(mat4(1.0f),(float)currenttime*45.0f,vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f))`;

Actually this changes nothing ;)
The other thing is, that i often read about `glRotatef` etc.For what are these Calls, when i use Matrices to translate or rotate my Objecct?

I use GLFW,GLEW and GLM.

Hope someone can help me out with this.(I know there are plenty Threads about this, but most of them are using other Librarys or are deprecated)

Comment: do you actually use the model matrix in your shader?

Comment: yep, my fault, the rotation is applied, but i want it to rotate constanty, like an animation

Comment: then you need to keep redrawing, some libs don't trigger a redraw unless they need to (a portion of the window gets revealed/the program says it needs redrawing)

Comment: i dont think there is a redraw function in glfw or glew O.o maye i am missing it

Comment: `glRotate` is legacy OpenGL. How are you drawing your cube ? The simplest way to redraw it is just drawing it again and again, in a loop.